# Modifying html repsonse from a webserver before it reaches the browser using a webserver plugin?

Tags: apache, http, webserver, conceptual

The question is as simple as the title. I have a webapp (I have no clue as to what technology it was built on or what appserver it is running on). However, I do know that this webapp is being served by an Apache Server/ IIS Server / IBM Http Server. Now, I would like to have a plugin/ module / add-on at the web-server end, which would parse/truncate/cut/regex the http response (based on the requested url's pattern), and mask(encrypt/shuffle/substitute) a set of fields in this response based on different parameters(user's LDAP permissions in the intranet / user's geo-location if on the internet, etc) and send the altered response back to the user.

So, Is there an easy answer to creating such plugins/modules/add-ons? How feasible is this approach of creating extra software at the webserver, when you want to mask sensitive information in a webapp without modfying the web-app code? Are there any tools that help you do this for Apache?

And, finally, is this just a really crazy thing to try?!

Comment: It's easiest to modify the web application.  Are you talking about a specific application?  Perhaps we could help you figure out what container it's using.

Comment: @Jeremy: This is the concept behind a data masking product/solution that we are gathering requirements for. The product has to dynamically mask values in the generated html response irrespective of the application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each webserver will have its own way of doing so.

There is no universal plugin architecture for webservers.

In IIS you would write an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ff8w4a(VS.71).aspx) or [HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858(VS.71).aspx), or possibly an [ISAPI Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610.aspx). You can also directly interact with the http response using the [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.response(VS.71).aspx) object exposed by the [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext_members%28VS.71%29.aspx).

With apache, there are different modules that can do what you want ([mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html), for example).

I don't know anything about WebSphere, but I am certain it also has similar mechanisms.

What you are asking is required by most web applications, so would be either built in or very easy to do.

Comment: @Oded what are these different modules?

Comment: I understand that there would be no universal plugin, however, if I would like to understand what plugins are available on each of the popular webservers in market.

Comment: @Jay - Updated answer with some specifics

Comment: mod_headers, can only customize HTTP request and reponse headers, if I am not wrong. Are there any alternatives for Apache?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add a plug-in using the web application container.  For example, if it's Tomcat, you can add a filter or valve.

If you want to plug-in to the web server, you'd need to write a custom module using the API of whichever web server is being used.

If all else fails, you could always wrap the entire server in a reverse proxy.  All requests would go through your proxy and that would give you the opportunity to modify the requests and the responses.